# How can I rewrite this LINQ query with reflection

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, reflection

So I had written this LINQ query using reflection, and later found out it isn't supported. What would be the best way to get the same functionality from this code?

```
List<Profile> profilesFromUUID = await MobileService.GetTable<Profile>().Where(p => typeof(Profile)
.GetProperty(handler.Name + "UUID").GetValue(p) == obj.uuid).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the reflection to create the query, not in the query. Consider:

```
public static IQueryable<Profile> Filter(
  this IQueryable<Profile> source, string name, Guid uuid)
{
  // .<name>UUID
  var property = typeof(Profile).GetProperty(name + "UUID");

  // p
  var parExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Profile));

  // p.<name>UUID
  var methodExp = Expression.Property(parExp, property);     

  // uuid
  var constExp = Expression.Constant(uuid, typeof(Guid));    

  // p.<name>UUID == uuid
  var binExp = Expression.Equal(methodExp, constExp);                  

  // p => p.<name>UUID == uuid
  var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Profile, bool>>(binExp, parExp);

  // source.Where(p => p.<name>UUID == uuid)
  return source.Where(lambda);
}
```

This builds up the expression first (so if `name` was "Test" it would create the expression corresponding with `p => p.TestUUID == uuid` and then uses that in the call to `Where`.

Because this step is done first, rather than within the expression itself, there's no need for the query engine to try to translate `typeof` or `GetProperty()` into SQL (which it of course, couldn't do).

So:

```
var filtered = MobileService.GetTable<Profile>().Filter(handler.Name, obj.uuid);
```

Returns an `IQueryable<Profile>` with the appropriate `Where` attached. And so:

```
var profilesFromUUID = await MobileService.GetTable<Profile>().Filter(handler.Name, obj.uuid).ToListAsync();
```

Will as a whole first use reflection to build the query, then apply the query, then produce a list from it asynchrously and then wait for its results.

It's worth noting that since `Filter()` will accept any `IQueryable<Profile>` they can be either chained or unioned. So:

```
MobileService.GetTable<Profile>().Filter("A", uuid0).Filter("B", uuid1);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
from p in MobileService.GetTable<Profile>() where p.AUUID = uuid0 && p.BUUID == uuid1
```

And:

```
MobileService.GetTable<Profile>().Filter("A", uuid0).Union(
  MobileService.GetTable<Profile>().Filter("B", uuid1))
```

Is equivalent to:

```
from p in MobileService.GetTable<Profile>() where p.AUUID = uuid0 || p.BUUID == uuid1
```

A more generalised version would be:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> FilterByNamedProperty<TSource, TValue>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, string propertyName, TValue value)
{
  var property = typeof(TSource).GetProperty(propertyName);
  var parExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource));
  var methodExp = Expression.Property(parExp, property);
  var constExp = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue));
  var binExp = Expression.Equal(methodExp, constExp);
  var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(binExp, parExp);
  return source.Where(lambda);
}
```

Then while you have to do the `+ "UUID"` in the calling code, you can use this to do analogous queries with any `IQueryable<>` of any element type.

Comment: How would I use `var profilesFromUUID = await MobileService.GetTable<Profile>().Filter(handler.Name, obj.uuid).ToListAsync();` Since `Filter` isn't a method derived `MobileService.GetTable<>()` ?

Comment: Oh I guess it needs to be used like an extension?

Comment: Yes, hence the `this` in the method's signature. Making it an extension makes it analogous to `Where`, and indeed, that makes me think of a more general version.

Answer (score 1):

How about just compare all property name? By definition UUID *would* not have collision anyway. Since `Profile` is just a data class, the # of the property for UUID is fixed.

```
List<Profile> profilesFromUUID = await MobileService.GetTable<Profile>()
    .Where(p => 
        p.A_UUID == obj.uuid || 
        p.B_UUID == obj.uuid ||
        p.C_UUID == obj.uuid)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Or add a method (extension method) for Profile like:

```
public static Guid GetUUIDByTableName(this Profile value, string tableName)
{
    switch (tableName)
    {
        case "A_": return value.A_UUID;
        case "B_": return value.B_UUID;
        default: return Guid.Empty;
    }
}


List<Profile> profilesFromUUID = await MobileService.GetTable<Profile>()
    .Where(p => p.GetUUIDByTableName(handler.Name) == obj.uuid)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Well that certainly is one approach to it. However the issue is the Profile table has foreign keys to a lot of other tables, all with their own uuid. So I need to find the specific uuid that matches `ForeignKeyTableName + UUID` string. I figure there would be a better way to do it since I know the string value of the uuid I'm looking for

Comment: @DillonDrobena I don't think adding the condition `(handler.Name == "A_" && p.A_UUID == obj.uuid)` help much in the performance.. Comparison of UID should be good enough.

Comment: What I meant to say is handler.Name contains the information I need to find the property immediately. So, for example (using reflection) `handler.Name = TableA` so by using reflection I can immediately get the property I'm looking for, instead of having to see if `obj.uuid == TableA.uuid || obj.uuid == TableB.uuid || ... || TableZ.uuid = obj.uuid` I'll use your suggestion if I can't find a way to use reflection in the query

Comment: You need to add code to allow `GetUUIDByTableName` to be executed as SQL or else it won't work in with the query provider any more than the original code in the question will.

Comment: The switch approach could work with the database if perhaps you took an `IQueryable<Profile>`, applied the `Where` in the switch, and then returned the `IQueryable<Profile>` produced.