# Why can't I use a range value's property as a parameter when calling a method in a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Where this is my test function:

```
public bool Test(string a, string b)
{
     return a.Contains(b);
}
```

Why does this work:

```
var airplanes = _dataContext.Airplanes.Where(p => Test("abc", "a"));
```

And this work:

```
string s = "abc";
var airplanes = _dataContext.Airplanes.Where(p => Test(s, "a"));
```

And *this* works:

```
var airplanes = _dataContext.Airplanes.Where(p => Test(new Random().Next(1, 10).ToString(), "1"));
```

And this work:

```
var airplanes = _dataContext.Airplanes.Where(p => p.Status.Contains("a"));
```

But this doesn't work:

```
var airplanes = _dataContext.Airplanes.Where(p => Test(p.Status.ToString(), "a");
```

And instead throws the error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
>   occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll
>
> Additional information: Method 'Boolean Test(System.String,
>   System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Originally I was passing the entire `p` variable to the function and thought maybe the problem was that the parameter was a custom, non SQL recognized class, so then I made the parameters just string properties of the class but it didn't solve anything.

Why can I not use the range variable's property as a parameter? Is there a way to get around this? Because that means instead of incredibly ugly linq queries I can break it up into nice small methods.

**Edit:** Also, why does [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/97674/38930) example work when it appears to be doing the same thing, passing the property of the iterated variable as a parameter:

```
private bool IsInRange(DateTime dateTime, decimal max, decimal min)
{
    decimal totalMinutes = Math.Round((dateTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes, 0);
    return totalMinutes <= max && totalMinutes > min;
}  

// elsewhere

.Where(m => IsInRange(m.DateAndTime, 30, 0));
```

Comment: I'm surprised the example in your edit works. At first guess I'd say something must be moving out of EF and into linq to objects (where all of these should work) but I can't see what's doing that either. I shall have to experiment when I add that promised bit about creating expressions.

Comment: Okay, that last one has something missing. For a start the first line assigns a `double` to a `decimal` without a cast, which isn't allowed, and if I fix that I get `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsInRange(System.DateTime, System.Decimal, System.Decimal)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`. If you're getting that to work there's something about it that you aren't putting into this question.

Comment: barnacle.m responded to my comment in the link to that example saying "You can call functions in linq queries as long as you're not querying the database itself in your query, otherwise it thinks you're trying to translate things to SQL, so what I do is pull the list from the db, then run linq queries on that list object." I added an answer explaining this.

Comment: Ah yes. Then it's linq-to-objects and instead of translating .NET into SQL it's translating .NET into .NET, which is a different proposition. I thought you meant you'd actually got it working, and hence suspected, "At first guess I'd say something must be moving out of EF"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out in the example I was looking at the `Where` method wasn't being run on the database itself, but a list already pulled from the database.

ie. this doesn't work:

```
var airplanes = _dataContext.Airplanes.Where(p => Test(p.Status.ToString(), "a");
```

but this does:

```
var airplanes = _dataContext.Airplanes.ToList().Where(p => Test(p.Status.ToString(), "a");
```

Although in my case that sort of defeats the purpose of doing LINQ instead of iteration.

Comment: If you **do** have to force something up into memory, then favour `.AsEnumerable()` rather than `ToList()` unless you've a good reason otherwise. The former will filter each item as they come, while the latter will first load every single item into memory, and only start filtering once that's done.

Answer (score 1):

In the first two cases, the call to Test doesn't relate to the parameter in the lambda, so they both reduce to `p => true`.

In the third this similarly happens, though it'll reduce to `p => true` sometimes, and `p => false` sometimes, but either way when it comes to creating the expression, the result of calling `Test` is found and then feed into the expression as a constant.

In the fourth the expression includes sub-expressions accessing a property of an entity and calling `Contains`, both of which EF understands and can turn into SQL.

In the fifth the expression contains sub-expressions accessing a property and calling `Test`. EF doesn't understand how to translate the call to `Test` so you need to either associate it with a SQL function, or rewrite `Test` so it creates an expression rather than calculating the result directly.

More on expressions as promised:

Let's start with two things that you may already know all about, but if you don't then the rest will be harder to understand.

The first is what `p => p.Status.Contains("a")` actually means.

Which is, on its own, absolutely nothing. Unlike most expressions in C# lambdas can't have a type without a context.

`1 + 3` has a type, which is `int` and hence in `var x = 1 + 3` the compiler gives `x` the type `int`. Even `long x = 1 + 3` starts with the `int` expression `1 + 3` and then casts it to `long` after that.

`p => p.Status.Contains("a")` doesn't have a type. Even `(Airplane p) => p.Status.Contains("a")` doesn't have a type, and so `var λ = (Airplane p) => p.Status.Contains("a");` isn't allowed.

Instead the type of a lambda expression will be either a delegate type or an `Expression` strongly typed to a delegate. So all of these are allowed (and mean something):

```
Func<Airplane, bool> funcλ = p => p.Status.Contains("a");
Expression<Func<Airplane, bool>> expFuncλ = p => p.Status.Contains("a");
delegate bool AirplanePredicate(Airplane plane);
AirplanePredicate delλ = p => p.Status.Contains("a");
Expression<AirplanePredicate> expDelλ = p => p.Status.Contains("a");
```

Okay. Maybe you knew that, if not you do now.

The second thing is what `Where` actually does in Linq.

The `Queryable` form of `Where` (we'll ignore the `Enumerable` form for now, and come back to it) is defined thus:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
```

`IQueryable<T>` represents something that can obtain 0 or more items. It can do four things, through four methods:

1. Give you an enumerator to enumerate through those items (inherited from `IEnumerable<T>`).
2. Tell you what type of item it has (which will be `typeof(T)` but it's inherited from `IQueryable` where its not as obvious).
3. Tell you what its query provider is.
4. Tell you what its expression is.

Now, those last two are the important bits here.

If you start with `new List<Airplane>().AsQueryable` then the query provider will be a `EnumerableQuery<Airplane>` which is a class that handles dealing with querys about in-memory enumerations of `Airplane`, and its expression will represent returning that list.

If you start with `_dataContext.Airplanes` the provider will be a `System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider` which is a class that handles dealing with EF queries about databases, and its expression will represent running `SELECT * FROM Airplanes` on a database and then creating an object for each row returned.

Now, the job of `Where` is to get the provider to create a new `IQueryable` that represents filtering the results of the expression we start with according to the `Expression<Func<Airplane, bool>>` passed to it.

The fun bit is that this is wonderfully self-referencial: The expression returned by `Where` when you call it with arguments of `IQueryable<Airplane>` and `Expression<Func<Airplane, bool>>` in fact represents calling `Where` with arguments of `IQueryable<Airplane>` and `Expression<Func<Airplane, bool>>`! It's like calling `Where` results in `Where` saying "hey, you should call `Where` here".

So, what happens next?

Well, sooner or later we do some operation that results in an `IQueryable` not being used to return another `IQueryable` but some other object representing the results of a query. For the sake of simplicity let's say we just start enumerating through the results of our single `Where`.

If it were Linq-to-objects then what we'd have is a queryable with an expression that means:

> Take the `Expression<Func<Airplane, bool>>` and compile it so you have a `Func<Airplane, bool>` delegate. Cycle through every element in the list, calling that delegate with it. If the delegate returns `true` then `yield` that element, otherwise don't.

(This incidentally is what the `Enumerable` version of `Where` does directly with a `Func<Airplane, bool>` instead of an `Expression<Func<Airplane, bool>>`. Remember when I said that the result of `Where` was an expression saying "hey, you should call `Where` here"? That's pretty much what it does, but because the provider now picks the `Enumerable` form of `Where` and uses the `Func<Airplane, bool>` rather than the `Expression<Func<Airplane, bool>>`, we get the results we want. This also means that as long as the operations provided on `IQueryable<T>` have an equivalent provided on `IEnumerable<T>` linq-to-objects can cater for everything linq generally caters for).

But this is not linq-to-objects, it's EF so what we have is an expression that means:

> Take the `Expression<Func<Airplane, bool>>` and turn it into a SQL boolean expression such as can be used in a SQL `WHERE` clause. Then add that as a `WHERE` clause to the earlier expression (which translates to `SELECT * FROM Airplanes`).

The tricky bit here is "and turn it into a SQL boolean expression".

When your lambda was `p => p.Status.Contains("a")` then the SQL could be produced of (depending on SQL version) `CONTAINS (Status, 'a')` or `Status LIKE '%a%'` or something else for a different type of database. The end result is hence `SELECT * FROM Airplanes WHERE Status LIKE '%a%'` or so on. EF knows how to break down that expression into component expressions, and how to turn `.Status` into a column access and how to turn `string`'s `Contains(string value)` into SQL where clauses.

When your lambda was `p => Test(p.Status.ToString(), "a")` the result was a `NotSupportedException` because EF does not know how to turn your `Test` method into SQL.

Okay. That's the meat, lets get to the pudding.

> Can you elaborate on what you mean by "rewrite Test so it creates an expression rather than calculating the result directly".

A problem here is that I don't know quite what your end goal was, as in just where you wanted to be flexible. So I'm going to do something that does the equivalent of `.Where(p => Test(p.Status.ToString(), someStringParameter))` in three ways; an easy way, a pretty easy way, and a hard way, where they can be made more flexible in a variety of ways.

First the easiest way:

```
public static class AirplaneQueryExtensions
{
  public static IQueryable<Airplane> FilterByStatus(this IQueryable<Airplane> source, string statusMatch)
  {
    return source.Where(p => p.Status.Contains(statusMatch));
  }
}
```

Here you can use `_dataContext.Airplanes.FilterByStatus("a")` and it is as if you'd used your working `Where()`. Because that's precisely what it is doing. We haven't really done a lot here, though there certainly is scope for DRY on more complicated `Where()` calls.

Roughly equally easy:

```
public static Expression<Func<Airplane, bool>> StatusFilter(string sought)
{
  return p => p.Status.Contains(sought);
}
```

Here you can use `_dataContext.Airplanes.Where(StatusFilter("a"))` and againt it's pretty much the same as if you'd used your working `Where()`. Again, we haven't done a lot here, but there's scope for DRY if the filter were more complicated.

Now for the fun version:

```
public static Expression<Func<Airplane, bool>> StatusFilter(string sought)
{
  var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Airplane), "p");                      // p
  var property = typeof(Airplane).GetProperty("Status");                        // .Status
  var propExp = Expression.Property(param, property);                           // p.Status
  var soughtExp = Expression.Constant(sought);                                  // sought
  var contains = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[]{ typeof(string) }); // .Contains(string)
  var callExp = Expression.Call(propExp, contains, soughtExp);                  // p.Status.Contains(sought)
  var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Airplane, bool>>(callExp, param);         // p => p.Status.Contains(sought);
  return lambda;
}
```

This does pretty much exactly the same as the previous version of `StatusFilter` does behind the scenes, except that identifies types, methods and properties using .NET metadata tokens and we use `typeof()` and names.

As the comments in each line show, the first line obtains an expression representing a property. We don't really need to give it a name since we won't be using it directly in source-code, but we call it `"p"` anyway.

The next line gets the `PropertyInfo` for `Status` and the subsequent creates an expression representing getting that for `p`, hence `p.Status`.

The next line creates an expression representing the constant value of `sought`. While `sought` isn't a constant generally, it is in terms of the overall expression we are creating (this is why EF was able to treat `Test("abc", "a")` as a constant `true` rather than having to translate it).

The next line gets the `MethodInfo` for `Contains` and in the next line we create an expression representing calling that on the result of `p.Status` with `sought` as an argument.

And finally we create an expression that ties them all together into the equivalent of `p => p.Status.Contains(sought)`, and return it.

This is clearly a lot more work than just doing `p => p.Status.Contains(sought)`. And well, that's sort of the point of having lambdas for expressions in C#, so that we normally don't have to do that work.

Indeed, to have a true expression-based equivalent of your `Test` we find ourselves doing:

```
public static MethodCallExpression Test(Expression a, string b)
{
  return Expression.Call(a, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[]{ typeof(string) }), Expression.Constant(b));
}
```

But then to use it we need to do more expression based work, because we can't just `p => Test(p.Status, "a")` because `p.Status` isn't an expression in that context. We have to do:

```
public static Expression<Func<Airplane, bool>> UseTest(string b)
{
  var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Airplane));
  return Expression.Lambda<Func<Airplane, bool>>(Test(Expression.Property(param, typeof(Airplane).GetProperty("Status")), b), param);
}
```

And now finally we can use `_dataContext.Airplanes.UseTest("a")`. Phew!

The expression-based approach has two advantages though.

1. We can use it if we want to do some manipulation with the expressions beyond want lambdas allow direction, such as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30795217/400547 where they're use alongside reflection to be able to specify the property to access as a string.
2. You hopefully know enough about how linq works behind the scenes to know all you need to know to understand fully why some of the queries in your question were working and some where not.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Can you elaborate on what you mean by "rewrite Test so it creates an expression rather than calculating the result directly"?

Comment: I'll show an example of that tomorrow, as it's time for bed for me now. It's rather convoluted, but does show a lot about how the more convenient linq expressions work, so worth looking at.

Comment: Hah, fair enough. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

LINQ to Entities has to know how to translate your code into SQL query it can run against database.

When you use *(I removed `ToString` call from the code you posted, because `ToString` doesn't work with LINQ to Entities)*:

```
var airplanes = _dataContext.Airplanes.Where(p => p.Status.Contains("a"));
```

compiler translates your lambda into Expression Tree that LINQ provider can traverse and generate proper SQL:

> **You can have the C# or Visual Basic compiler create an expression tree for you based on an anonymous lambda expression**, or you can create expression trees manually by using the `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace.
>
> *quote from [Expression Trees (C# and Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)*

It knows how to translate call to `IEnumerable.Contains` because it's one of the methods that was added to it as 'known' stuff - it knows it has to generate `IN` statement the same way it knows that `!=` should be translated into `<>` in SQL.

When you use

```
var airplanes = _dataContext.Airplanes.Where(p => Test(p.Active, "a");
```

all the Expression Tree has is `Test` methods call, which LINQ provider knows nothing about. It also can't inspect it's content to find that it's actually just wrapping around `Contains` call, because the methods get's compiled to IL, not to Expression Tree.

***Appendix***

As of why `Where(p => Test("abc", "a"))` word and `Where(p => Test(s, "a"))` doesn't I'm not 100% sure, but my guess is LINQ provider is smart enough to see that you're calling it with two constant values, so it just tries to execute it and see if it can get a value back, that could be treated as constant in the SQL query.

Comment: At first the error made sense because I figured there was just no way LINQ would understand what was in the `Test` method like you said, but when I noticed it *is* able to run the method when other parameters are passed to it, that's what's surprising to me. Especially considering this function works and also uses a property of the range variable: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/97674/38930

Comment: It's probably smart enough to see that you're calling it with two constant values, so it just tries to execute it and see if it can get a value back, that could be treated as constant in the SQL query. I've never run into such a case before.

Comment: I added another example in the question. It also uses the property as a parameter, so I don't think it would just be treating the value as a constant.

Comment: This one is really strange. You sure it's still LINQ to Entites and not LINQ to Objects? The link to codereview.se doesn't say it's LINQ to Entites. LINQ to Objects doesn't work on Expression Trees, it works on delegates and you can use any code you want in the queries there.

Comment: Linq to objects can work on expression trees. `Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Where(i => i % 2 == 0).Select(i => i.ToString())` doesn't use an expression tree ,but `Enumerable.Range(0, 100).AsQueryable().Where(i => i % 2 == 0).Select(i => i.ToString())` does and you can examine its `Expression` property. Executing it pretty much produces, and runs, the former.